# Fastest way to find distinct matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, rdbms

I have two tables A and B. Both have same structure. We find matching records between these two. Here are the scripts

```
CREATE TABLE HRS.A
(
F_1 NUMBER(5,0),
F_2 NUMBER(5,0),
F_3 NUMBER(5,0)
);

CREATE TABLE HRS.B
(
F_1 NUMBER(5,0),
F_2 NUMBER(5,0),
F_3 NUMBER(5,0)
);

INSERT INTO hrs.a VALUES (1,1000,2000);
INSERT INTO hrs.a VALUES (2,1100,8000);
INSERT INTO hrs.a VALUES (3,4000,3000);
INSERT INTO hrs.a VALUES (4,2000,5000);
INSERT INTO hrs.a VALUES (5,5000,3000);
INSERT INTO hrs.a VALUES (6,6000,6000);
INSERT INTO hrs.a VALUES (7,3000,7000);
INSERT INTO hrs.a VALUES (8,1100,9000);

INSERT INTO hrs.b VALUES (1,4000,2000);
INSERT INTO hrs.b VALUES (2,6000,8000);
INSERT INTO hrs.b VALUES (3,1000,3000);
INSERT INTO hrs.b VALUES (4,2000,5000);
INSERT INTO hrs.b VALUES (5,8000,3000);
INSERT INTO hrs.b VALUES (6,1100,6000);
INSERT INTO hrs.b VALUES (7,5000,7000);
INSERT INTO hrs.b VALUES (8,1000,9000);
```

To find matching records

```
SELECT a.F_1 A_F1, b.F_1 B_F1 FROM HRS.A, HRS.B WHERE A.F_2 = B.F_2
```

results

```
A_F1 B_F1
3   1
6   2
1   3
4   4
8   6
2   6
5   7
1   8
```

Now i want to remove duplicate entries in both columns separately e.g. 1 is repeating in A_F1 (regardless of B_F1) so row # 3(1-3) and 8(1-8) will be removed. Now 6 is repeating in B_F1 (regardless of A_F1) so row # 5(8-6) and 6(2-6) will be removed. Final result should be

```
A_F1 B_F1
3   1
6   2
4   4
5   7
```

**Now most important part**, These two tables contain **500,000 records each**. I was first finding and inserting these matching records into a temp table, then removing duplicate from first column then from second column and then selecting all from temp table. This is too too slow. How can i achieve this as faster as possible?

**Edit # 1**

I executed following statements multiple times to generate 4096 records in each table

```
INSERT INTO hrs.a SELECT F_1 + 1, F_2 + 1, 0 FROM hrs.a;
INSERT INTO hrs.b SELECT F_1 + 1, F_2 + 1, 0 FROM hrs.b;
```

Now i executed all answers and found these

```
Rachcha     9.11 secs   OK
techdo      1.14 secs   OK
Gentlezerg  577  msecs  WRONG RESULTS
Justin      218  msecs  OK
```

Even @Justin took 37.69 secs for 65,536 records in each (total = 131,072)

Waiting for more optimized answers as actual number of records are 1,000,000 :)

Here is the execution plan of the query based on Justin's answer

[image]

Comment: i don't understand exactly what you want to do here but the best way to get rid of duplicate rows in a table with a lot of rows is to use the analytic function `RANK`. if you also join another table and perform delete then the optimizer could utilize the sort that is already made by the function.

Comment: @haki I am not aware with RANK, please post its usage in this case as answer

Comment: i cant test this but it's something like that `delete from a 
where rowid in (
 //  fetch the rowid - this is going directly to the row 
 // - no need for range scan or index scan   
 select  rid
 from  (
   select  b.rowid as rid, 
     // give each combination of keys c1,c2,c3 a distinct rank 
     rank() over (partition by c1,c2,c3) as rnk
   from  b)
   // we want to keep only one row
 where  rnk > 1`

Comment: @bjan, can you show the execusion plans ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade If you mean EP of each answer then you can check it yourself at sqlfiddle.com, otherwise please explain

Comment: @bjan, a full execussion plan from your schema, will show which indexes are used and how the optimizer decides what to do. The most interesting one should be Justin's because the other answers probably don't use any indexes

Comment: @A.B.Cade Execution plan of Justin's query on my actual tables is provided

Comment: @bjan: why your final result is 4 numbers, not 6 in both columns? Only 1s removed from A and 6s removed from B...

Comment: @Art once a duplicate value is found in any column, whole row(column1 + column2) will be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of these solutions are taking time, the best one (Justin) took almost 45 mins without even returning for 2 million records. I ended up with inserting matching records in a temp table and then removing duplicates and i found it much faster than these solutions with this data set.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
select A_F1, B_F1 From(
  SELECT a.F_1 A_F1, b.F_1 B_F1, 
    count(*) over (partition by a.F_1 order by a.F_1) C1,
    count(*) over (partition by b.F_1 order by b.F_1) C2
  FROM HRS.A A, HRS.B B WHERE A.F_2 = B.F_2
)x 
where C1=1 and C2=1;
```

How about an `INNER JOIN` instead? Please check with this query.

```
select A_F1, B_F1 From(
  SELECT a.F_1 A_F1, b.F_1 B_F1, 
    count(*) over (partition by a.F_1 order by a.F_1) C1,
    count(*) over (partition by b.F_1 order by b.F_1) C2
  FROM HRS.A A INNER JOIN HRS.B B ON A.F_2 = B.F_2
)x 
where C1=1 and C2=1;
```

Comment: second is not much better than first

Comment: @bjan Okay, will try in a different way... I don't have much to test actually!

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer.

See this **[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dedbb/8)** here.

I used the following code:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT a.f_1 AS a_f_1, b.f_1 AS b_f_1
             FROM a JOIN b ON a.f_2 = b.f_2)
SELECT *
  FROM x x1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM x x2
                    WHERE (x2.a_f_1 = x1.a_f_1
                           AND x2.b_f_1 != x1.b_f_1)
                       OR (x2.a_f_1 != x1.a_f_1
                           AND x2.b_f_1 = x1.b_f_1)
                  )
;
```

**EDIT**

I used to following code that runs within 14 ms on [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dedbb/8). I removed the common table expression and observed that the query performance improved.

```
SELECT a1.f_1 AS a_f1, b1.f_1 AS b_f1
  FROM a a1 JOIN b b1 ON a1.f_2 = b1.f_2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM a a2 JOIN b b2 ON a2.f_2 = b2.f_2
                    WHERE (a2.f_1 = a1.f_1
                           AND b2.f_1 != b1.f_1)
                       OR (a2.f_1 != a1.f_1
                           AND b2.f_1 = b1.f_1))
;
```

**Output:**

```
A_F_1   B_F_1
3           1
6           2
4           4
5           7
```

Comment: Yes it has improved, now resulting in 700 ms.

Comment: It will keep improving as the tables are already cached! The first time you ran, the previous query took about 9 seconds. This was when the result set was cached. Since then any query you run of a similar kind will yield results faster.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dedbb/10)**

```
SELECT a.f_1 AS a_f_1, 
       b.f_1 AS b_f_1
FROM a JOIN b ON a.f_2 = b.f_2
WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM a aa JOIN b bb ON aa.f_2 = bb.f_2
           WHERE aa.f_1 = a.f_1 )
AND 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM a aa JOIN b bb ON aa.f_2 = bb.f_2
           WHERE bb.f_1 = b.f_1 )
```

Result:

```
| A_F_1 | B_F_1 |
-----------------
|     3 |     1 |
|     6 |     2 |
|     4 |     4 |
|     5 |     7 |
```

Answer (score 1):

According to @techdo 's answer, I think this can be better:

```
select A_F1, B_F1 From(
  SELECT a.F_1 A_F1, b.F_1 B_F1,a.F_2,
    count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY A.F_2) C
  FROM HRS.A A, HRS.B B WHERE A.F_2 = B.F_2
)x 
where C=1 ;
```

The existence of multi rows is due to the same f_2. This SQL has only one count..over,so you said you have vast data, I think this would be a little faster.

Comment: I didn't consider the situation that one  F_1 has many corresponding f_2 in one table ...